# max value within both an array and non-array are given

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I am creating a function that will lookup for the maximum value within an array. However, say I have this example,

```
function MaxArray($arr)
{
    return max($arr);
}
$arr = array(array(141,151,161), 2, 3, array(101, 202, array(303,404)));
print_r(MaxArray($arr));
```

This will return values `Array ( [0] => 141 [1] => 151 [2] => 161 )`

What I want for an output is to get 404 because it is the highest value in the array. Any insights? Thanks.

Comment: flatten the array first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a modification of your function

```
function MaxInArray ($arr) {
    $m = NULL;
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) $v = MaxInArray($v);
        if (is_null($m) || $v > $m) $m = $v;
    }
    return $m;
}
```

Made it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many features built-in to flatten or recursively walk the array, e.g. [`array_walk_recursive`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive). For example combine with an [anonymous function<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) this can be solved with some little code:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use(&$max) {$max = max($v, $max);});

var_dump($max); # int(404)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KgiRju)